# Can pyautogui be used to prevent windows screen lock?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I tried to use this script to prevent windows screen lock. The script works for moving the mouse, but it doesn't prevent windows 10 from locking.

```
import pyautogui
import time
import win32gui, win32con
import os

Minimize = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
win32gui.ShowWindow(Minimize, win32con.SW_MINIMIZE)

x = 1

while x == 1:
    pyautogui.moveRel(1)
    pyautogui.moveRel(-1)
    time.sleep (300)
```

Comment: I don't know about Pyauto, but the screen lock *can* be prevented simply by moving the mouse. I wrote a script using Java's robot library that randomly moves the mouse by one pixel every minute. It was able to delay the lock indefinitely.

Comment: Try more than one pixel and maybe use `moveTo` vs `moveRel`?

Comment: @zhqiat I attempted to do this with moveTo at 50 pixel distance and it did not work.

Answer (score 24):

Yes it can. But sadly not by moving mouse which I don't know why and would like to know. So, my suggestion is to use pyautogui **KEYBOARD EVENTS** if possible. I have solved my problems by using **VOLUME-UP** & **VOLUME-DOWN** keys. Example code is provided below:

```
import pyautogui
import time

while True:
    pyautogui.press('volumedown')
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.press('volumeup')
    time.sleep(5)
```

You can use any other keys if you want.

Answer (score 12):

```
import ctypes

# prevent
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetThreadExecutionState(0x80000002)
# set back to normal
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetThreadExecutionState(0x80000000)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate

Tested on python 3.9.1, win 10 64bit

Comment: thank you for this post. it took me a while to figure out 0x80000002 actually came from 0x8000000) + 0x00000002. Just in case this may help other folks