# Wake windows up from standby with python

Tags: python, pywin32

I have a programm that use pyautogui. There are some mouse moves, clicks etc. Computer goes to sleep mode and mouse moves doesn't work there. I want to programm auto waking up from sleep mode at time for my pyautogui script available. I find some answers with **SetWaitableTimer()** but can not to code it right. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: instead of using your script to wake things up, why not use Windows Task Scheduler to wake up the pc and run your script

Answer (score 1):

According to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58273482/can-pyautogui-be-used-to-prevent-windows-screen-lock)

You should use keyboard event which will make your computer active and doesn't let to go in sleep mode.

The code describes there was:

```
import pyautogui
import time

while True:
    pyautogui.press('volumedown')
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.press('volumeup')
    time.sleep(5)
```

Hope it helps!