# How to do pyautogui continue executing while screen windows is locked

Tags: python, pyautogui, robotics, robotic-scraping

I have this function thast works fine while the screen not is locked in windows 10.

```
def buscar_test():
    fw = pyautogui.getWindowsWithTitle('datos_carga.txt: Bloc de notas')
    fw = fw[0]
    fw.maximize()
    pyautogui.click(fw.center)

    #pyautogui.sleep(3)
    pyautogui.typewrite("Hello world")
    pyautogui.sleep(30)
    pyautogui.typewrite("Hello after windows locked")
```

But when the windows screen is locked this doesn´t work, Please any idea How do.?

While screen is locked in windows 10, continuing used pyautogui.

Comment: What do you mean by windows screen is locked?

Comment: @Farid Ibrahim When in windows you press "windows" + L to lock the pc

Comment: Or you can prevent it entirely ---> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58273482/can-pyautogui-be-used-to-prevent-windows-screen-lock